# How to apply order with include in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

How to sort Events table which is joined to the order table using Sequelize. Below given code I tried is not working as expected.

```
include:[ {
    model: Events,
    as: 'events',
    required: false,
    attributes: ['id','event_data','order_id'],
    order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
    where:{
      event_data: 'completed'
    }
  }],
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use **alias** in **order** if **alias** is used inside **include**

```
include:[ {
        model: Events,
        as: 'events',
        required: false,
        attributes: ['id','event_data','order_id'],
        where:{
          event_data: 'completed'
        }
      }],
      order: [
          ['created_at', 'ASC'],
          [{ model: Events, as: 'events'},'created_at','DESC']
      ],
```